# Width issue on chrome when select all and copy

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-email

When i try to apply our custom email signature in gmail, i found some bug on google chrome. When i try to select all and copy then paste to gmail signature field and do some check.

Google chrome output:

[image]

Instead giving `width: 100%` it will give you *fixed value* depend on your screen size. If you want to avoid this you can use other browser, i already try **Firefox** and it gives correct `width`.

This is the source code if you want to try.

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td width="200" style="border: 1px solid #888;padding: 40px;">test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Syfer i don't have, i just want to share this issue.

Comment: Stack overflow is where you post your questions if you running to any issues while coding. Read the rules to see where this should go.